# why I use scipy.io.savemat getting a row and a column but not two columns

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I get two data and I want to make it as a .mat file
so I used module scipy.io and scipy.io.savemat
but when I open the file I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6hhK.png)

I want to get two columns as 950x1 not 1x950

this is the code:

```
import scipy.io as sio

x = Ramanshift1[64:1014]
Hem_I_Nor = pd.Normalization(y3_arpls)
sio.savemat(Hem_path+'/matdata.mat',{'ramanshift':x,'ramanspectra':Hem_I_Nor})
```

x comes from a column
and Hem_I_Nor comes from pandas and all of this can be saved to .csv and two columns

Comment: in other words `np.array[z,y,x]==matlab(x,y,z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a numpy session:

```
In [25]: from scipy.io import savemat
In [26]: savemat('test.mat', {'x':np.ones((3,),int), 'y': np.ones((3,1),int), 'z
    ...: ': np.ones((1,3),int)})
```

In an Octave session, after `load`:

```
>> size(x),size(y),size(z)
ans =
   1   3

ans =
   3   1

ans =
   1   3
```

It's the 1d array that's made into a (1,n) matrix:

```
x =
  1  1  1
```

With 2d arrays, watch the `order`.  MATLAB uses `F`.  So

```
In [31]: np.arange(12).reshape(3,4,order='F')
Out[31]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

saves as

```
>> w
w = 
   0   3   6   9
   1   4   7  10
   2   5   8  11
```

Because of the inherent differences in array/matrix orders, transfering values from one to the other can be confusing.  The `savemat/loadmat` actions don't necessarily help.

Looking at the docs, there's also a `oned_as` parameter than controls whether a `(n,)` arrays is saved as (n,1) or (1,n).